# How to web scrape AQI from airnow?

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the current AQI in my location by beautifulsoup 4.

```
url = "https://www.airnow.gov/?city=Burlingame&state=CA&country=USA"

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")


aqi = soup.find("div", class_="aqi")
```

when I print the aqi, it is just empty div like this:

However, on the website, there should be a  element inside this div containing the aqi number that I want.

Comment: I also tried to select by copying the selector path. ```
aqi = soup.select("body > div.dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas > div.main-content > div > div > section > div > div > div > div.view-header > article > div > div > div > div.aq-dial-container.col-md-5.col-sm-6.col-md-offset-2.col-sm-offset-1 > div.aq-dial > div.bottom-half > div.current-aq-container > div.current-aq-data > div.aqi > b")
print(aqi)``` and it still returns an empty list.

Comment: It is because you need javascript. It render javascript to create this <b>45</b> element inside div class="aqi". Disable javascript on the page and you will see that div is empty. Try to use selenium or playwright.